# NSLayoutConstraint not assigned to a constant/variable

Tags: ios, swift

I'm learning `Swift` and came across this example for adding a constraint to a view:

```
artworkView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor).isActive = true
```

It's my understanding that since `constraint(equalTo:)` returns a `NSLayoutConstraint`, it would need to be assigned to a constant/variable. Otherwise, where exactly is this `NSLayoutConstraint` it created? How is it accessed in order to, say, deactivate it?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it creates and returns a constraint but if one already exists then it simply returns that.
You could store it in a variable for convenience or just access it using the same code.

```
artworkView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor).isActive = false
```